# Removing a string of files with rename

Tags: perl, regex, batch-rename

I have been trying to batch rename a bunch of files so that they are consistent and fit within the name structure that I have come up with. For instance,I am renaming comics, and so I have a directory that looks like this:

```
$ls *.cbr
Injustice - Gods Among Us 001 (2013) (Digital) (K6 of Ultron-Empire).cbr
Injustice - Gods Among Us 002 (2013) (Digital) (K6 of Ultron-Empire).cbr 
Injustice - Gods Among Us 003 (2013) (Digital) (K6 of Ultron-Empire).cbr
```

My goal is to use rename the files so they look like the following:

```
Injustice - Gods Among Us 001.cbr
Injustice - Gods Among Us 002.cbr
Injustice - Gods Among Us 003.cbr
```

So I tried the following:

```
rename -n 's/^\d{3}.\.cbr/^\ $1.cbr/' *.cbr
```

Was assuming that by delimiting to the first set up on the 3 digit issue, I could then change to rename everything starting from the beginning line (Injustice - God Among Us) and add in the 3 digit issue number (\d{3}) everything would pan out. Needless to say, it didn't.

Although I would like a little direction on how to get this solved, I really want to better understand how to leverage using pregex for future use.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding the meaning of the carat (`^`) line anchor - it does not mean 'look for a *pattern* starting with the following regex', it means 'look for a *line* starting with the following *pattern*' - which will of course not match any of your listed filenames, because the 001 ... 003 comes part way through the name.

What you are probably thinking of are Perl's *lookaround* constructs - for example, to limit your match to the portion of the name after the first 3-digit sequence, you can use a `(?<=\d{3})` *lookbehind*. Similarly, to limit the match to the portion before the `.cbr` suffix you could use the *lookaheaad* `(?=\.cbr)`. Finally you could match any characters between the lookbehind and the lookahead i.e. `.*`, and replace them with nothing:

```
$ rename -nv 's/(?<=\d{3}).*(?=.cbr)//' *.cbr
Injustice - Gods Among Us 001 (2013) (Digital) (K6 of Ultron-Empire).cbr renamed as Injustice - Gods Among Us 001.cbr
Injustice - Gods Among Us 002 (2013) (Digital) (K6 of Ultron-Empire).cbr renamed as Injustice - Gods Among Us 002.cbr
Injustice - Gods Among Us 003 (2013) (Digital) (K6 of Ultron-Empire).cbr renamed as Injustice - Gods Among Us 003.cbr
```

Note that there are usually several different ways to match and rename a particular set of files - I'm not sure this is the most efficient or robust however I hope it illustrates what I *think* you were shooting for.

Comment: Thanks to both responses the my question. The sad fact is that I wasn't even close to what I was trying to achieve. The first answer hit right on the head although I did have to do *[Dd]igital to automagically make things work. I really need to better work on my understanding of regex.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the `(2013) (Digital) (K6 of Ultron-Empire)` string is fixed in all files, you don't need anything too complex actually:

```
$ ls 
Injustice - Gods Among Us 001 (2013) (Digital) (K6 of Ultron-Empire).cbr
Injustice - Gods Among Us 002 (2013) (Digital) (K6 of Ultron-Empire).cbr
Injustice - Gods Among Us 003 (2013) (Digital) (K6 of Ultron-Empire).cbr
$ rename 's/ \(2013\) \(Digital\) \(K6 of Ultron\-Empire\)//g' *
$ ls
Injustice - Gods Among Us 001.cbr  Injustice - Gods Among Us 003.cbr
Injustice - Gods Among Us 002.cbr
```

I gave away flexibility for practicality. If you want to remove everything between `(...)` you can use even [more clever methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9589853/792066):

```
rename -n 's/ ([(].*Digital.*[)])//g' *
```

Also, your regex is not selecting anything actually. I would read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8582641/792066) to understand how `\d{3}` works.